# Increment a field Using Mongoose method

Tags: node.js

I have a small issue on node js, i want to increment a field value on the schema  each time a add a new item , i don' t know , if my step a correct, can you have a look?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const InvoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  name: {

    type: String,

    unique: true,

  },

  

  InvoiceSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {

    const db = await this.model("Invoice");

    const dbarray = await db.find();

    for (let i = 0; i < dbarray.length; i++) {

      this.name = `Invoice#${i}`;

    }

    next();

  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model("Invoice", InvoiceSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
const dbarray = await db.find();

for (let i = 0; i < dbarray.length; i++) {
  this.name = `Invoice#${i}`;
}
```

You can do like this

```
const count= await db.find().count();
this.name = `Invoice#${count}`;
```